# ¿Como listar solo un bucket en AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Creé un usuario en AWS para que solo interactúe con un bucket en especifico, pero al momento de entrar a la consola de S3 (web) el puede ver la lista de todos los buckets. Si bien, no puede modificar nada, me gustaria que no viera los nombres de los otros buckets que no le pertenecen.

El JSON con las policies es el siguiente

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que le estas dando permiso de listar **todos** los buckets en esta parte:

```
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

Intenta cambiar la políticas IAM asignada por esta (podrías analizar si es necesario que puedan ver la localización del bucket, sino también habría que quitar esta policy `s3:GetBucketLocation`):

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17", 
"Statement": [
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
},
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    ]
},
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    ]
} ]}
```